# Create a function outside of the class, which uses the value of returned method of the class

Tags: javascript, function, class

I'm trying to implement an external(out of class) the function who is happier from a value which is returned from a method inside another class.

```
class Mentor {

    constructor(name, mark) {
        this.name = name
        this.mark = mark
    }
    getHappiness() {
        return mark * 2
    }

let a = new Mentor('John', 10)
let b = new Mentor('Jerry', 9)

function whoIsHappier(c, d) {
    if ((c = this.Mentor.getHappiness()) > (d = this.Mentor.getHappiness())) {
        return c + ' is happier than ' + d
    } else if ((c = this.Mentor.getHappiness()) < (d = this.Mentor.getHappiness())) {
        return d + ' is happier than ' + c
    } else {
        return c + ' happiness is equal to ' + c + "'s happiness"
    }
}
console.log(whoIsHappier(a, b))
```

Comment: I suggest working through some basic tutorials. There's no need for `this` inside `whoIsHappier`, you don't need to reference a `Mentor` property, and there's no reason to assign back to your arguments. Just `if (c.getHappiness() > d.getHappiness())`. Also note that you're missing the closing `}` on your `class`. (I also recommend using meaningful variable and parameter names.)

Comment: Yes, I need to revise some basic stuff, definitely will do, 
However, in case I just write : (c.getHappiness() > d.getHappiness()) won't it compare the specific 2 objects? But want to compare any new object that I will create.
I changed to:
if (c.getHappiness() > d.getHappiness()) and got: 
[object Object] is happier than [object Object]
it's not referring to the objects values that I compare.

Comment: It will compare the two objects you pass into the function. *"...and got: [object Object] is happier than [object Object] it's not referring to the objects values that I compare."* Yes, it is. `[object Object]` is what you get when you use `+` to convert an object to a string (although with the code above it should be showing you `[object Mentor]`). To show the `name`, use `c.name + " is happier than " + d.name`.

Comment: Thank you T.J. I feel really dumb. But I learned something today. it works. Thank you again.

Comment: …and also `getHappiness` will need to `return this.mark * 2`